# Calling a CUDA "Hello World" from Haskell using the FFI gives wrong results

Tags: haskell, cuda, ffi

This is the standard Hello World CUDA file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

const int N = 7;
const int blocksize = 7;

__global__ void hello_kernel(char *a, int *b) {
    a[threadIdx.x] += b[threadIdx.x];
}

#define cudaCheckError() { \
    cudaError_t e=cudaGetLastError(); \
    if(e!=cudaSuccess) { \
        printf("Cuda failure %s:%d: '%s'\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,cudaGetErrorString(e)); \
        exit(0); \
    } \
}

void hello() {
    char a[N] = "Hello ";
    int b[N] = {15, 10, 6, 0, -11, 1, 0};

    char *ad;
    int *bd;
    const int csize = N*sizeof(char);
    const int isize = N*sizeof(int);

    printf("%s", a);

    cudaMalloc( (void**)&ad, csize );
    cudaMemcpy( ad, a, csize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaCheckError();

    cudaMalloc( (void**)&bd, isize );
    cudaMemcpy( bd, b, isize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaCheckError();

    dim3 dimBlock( blocksize, 1 );
    dim3 dimGrid( 1, 1 );
    hello_kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(ad, bd);
    cudaMemcpy( a, ad, csize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    cudaCheckError();

    cudaFree( ad );
    cudaCheckError();

    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

And its header:

```
-- hello.h
extern "C" 
void hello();
```

That's a Haskell file that calls such function:

```
-- test.hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Foreign.C
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr,nullPtr)

foreign import ccall "hello" hello :: IO ()

main = hello
```

I'm compiling it with:

```
nvcc hello.c -c -o hello.o
ghc test.hs -o test hello.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -optl-lcudart
```

Running that program with `./test` results in:

```
Hello Cuda failure hello.cu:32: 'no CUDA-capable device is detected'
```

Running the same program with a C `main()` that just calls `hello` produces `Hello World`, as expected.

How do I make Haskell detect the device correctly?

Comment: Why is there no CUDA API error checking in your code? "Wrong answer" usually equals "never ran". But without any error checking, how could you possibly know?

Comment: I just took the Hello World from the web. I might add some error checks and update the question.

Comment: You should be able to write a native C++ main which calls the hello function and check it works. It could be that your CUDA installation is broken, or it could be a haskell-CUDA problem, but at the moment it is extremely hard to say

Comment: I've done that, it does work. Anyway, updated the question.

Comment: So you have your answer. The runtime API fails to detect a valid device when called from whatever it is you are using in Haskell.

Comment: Okay. I updated the actual question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe unrelated, but I was able to reproduce your error on a Mac with separate on-board and discrete graphics cards. When "Automatic graphics switching" is enabled in System Preferences (and no 3D graphics applications are running), I get the same "no CUDA-capable device is detected" error.

When I turn off automatic graphics switching, it forces the Mac to use the discrete graphics card, and then the program runs as expected.

The purely C/CUDA-based version of the code doesn't seem to be affected by this preference and always works whether automatic switching is enabled or not.

Answer (score 4):

Using `ghc 7.8.3` and `nvcc V6.5.12`, I found that your code works as expected.  The only different thing that I did was name `hello.c` as `hello.cu`.

```
/:cuda_haskell> nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jul_17_19:13:24_CDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12
/:cuda_haskell> nvcc -o hello.o -c hello.cu
/:cuda_haskell> ghc main.hs -o hello_hs hello.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -optl-lcudart
Linking hello_hs ...
/:cuda_haskell> ./hello_hs
Hello World!
/:cuda_haskell> cat main.hs
-- main.hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Foreign.C
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr,nullPtr)

foreign import ccall "hello" hello :: IO ()

main = hello
```

Comment: Oh. That is weird. Maybe it is something specific to my machine, then. Sorry if that's the case, and thanks!