# Haskell FFI with CUDA using stack build tool set up?

Tags: haskell, cuda, haskell-stack

I have a project which is working quite nicely with haskell, stack, and some C code via FFI. I would like to add some CUDA code to offload some computations to the GPU. Kind of not sure how this needs to be configured?

in my .cabal file I simply have:

`c-sources: src/ccode/blah.c, src/ccode/blah.h, src/ccode/blah2.c, etc..
 cc-options:  -std=c99`

when i run stack build it nicely builds both the C and the haskell. How can I add CUDA to the mix?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442524/calling-a-cuda-hello-world-from-haskell-using-the-ffi-gives-wrong-results) may be of interest

Comment: Your question is about Haskell and CUDA. Why the C tag?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37643200/925978

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [cuda](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cuda) package. It lets you do some cool stuff like load pre-compiled ptx code at runtime.

Comment: thanks, the cuda package looks great! Do I need to know a lot about make files to work with it?

Answer (score 1):

You could manually compile the CUDA code before using cabal:

```
nvcc -c cudacode.c
```

Then build with cabal. Example `.cabal` file:

```
name:                package
version:             0.1
build-type:          Simple

executable main
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base
  extra-libraries:     stdc++
  ghc-options:         -pgmlg++ cudacode.o
  C-sources:           just_c.c, some_cpp.cpp
  Includes:            just_c.h, cudacode.h, some_cpp.h
```

Without C++, you can omit the `extra-libraries` field and the first `ghc-option`.

Alternatively, you can specify `nvcc` as the compiler for everything, and not have to compile it separately:

```
cabal install --with-gcc=/path/to/nvcc
```

Example `.cabal` file:

```
name:                package
version:             0.1
build-type:          Simple

executable main
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base
  extra-libraries:     stdc++
  ghc-options:         -pgmlg++
  C-sources:           just_c.c, cudacode.c, some_cpp.cpp
  Includes:            just_c.h, cudacode.h, some_cpp.h
```

Again, the `extra-libraries` and `ghc-options` are only necessary with C++.

Comment: Did you actually try the `--with-gcc=/path/to/gcc`? I've read that GHC is *very* picky about which compiler it uses, and I couldn't get g++ to work.